# How to send a database ID via a ResponseEntity?

Tags: spring-boot, response

I am using Spring Boot for my backend that is sending a JSON in the body of a ResponseEntity to a Vue.js frontend.

The JSON is also located in a MySQL database where it gets an ID. This ID is given to the JSON after it was generated, so I cannot change my JSON and include my ID in it.

So, I need to include this document ID in the ResponseEntity by other means (for providing a download-link to the document via a different REST endpoint).

This is how I return my ResponseEntity at the moment:

```
public static ResponseEntity<String> getOutput(DocumentFile outputFile, String format)
        throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    int documentID = outputFile.getId() + 1;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(getMediaTypeFromFormat(format));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseString = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(content);
    return responseString;
}
```

`documentID` is the ID I want to send with the JSON.

Can I include this ID somehow in the header or in the body or somewhere else? And how can I achieve that?

Comment: How does your URL look like? If you create a get request you will add this as a PathVariable

Comment: When sending the request from my frontend, the ID is unknown because this ID is generated when the generated JSON file is saved into my database. My download-API is just `/download/{id}`. My goal is to call this download-API from the frontend after the JSON from my other endpoint was received. My frontend should know the ID of the file when getting this JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the structure of your JSON object?

There are multiple approaches to this. 
a) return the ID value in a header, like:

```
public static ResponseEntity<String> getOutput(DocumentFile outputFile, String format)
        throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    int documentID = outputFile.getId() + 1;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "X-Custom-ID");
    headers.add("X-Custom-ID", String.valueOf(documentID));
    headers.setContentType(getMediaTypeFromFormat(format));

    ResponseEntity<String> responseString = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(content);
    return responseString;
}
```

b) create a custom return object, for example:

```
class CustomResponse {
  String id;  // would be the id
  String value;  // would be the json
}
```

c)

> This ID is given to the JSON after it was generated, so I cannot
>   change my JSON and include my ID in it.

Yes you can. Map your JSON to a domain object (with ObjectMapper), and add the ID to it.

Comment: How do you return the ID value in the header (Approach a)?

Comment: can you share how you return the ResponseEntity now?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. So the frontend now gets a header called: X-Custom-ID, with the value of the id.

Comment: I added the line `headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "X-Custom-ID");` to Option a), so the header can be accessed in my client application.